# Static Address in Dynamically Loaded DLL

Tags: function-hooking

I am trying to re-write the following function in my injected DLL.

```
mov edi,edi
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax, [sound.dll+1AE0]
push eax
mov ecx,[ebp+08]
mov eax,[ecx]
mov eax,[eax+0C]
push eax
call sound.dll+7C640
pop ebp
ret 0004
```

I am loading my DLL via CreateRemoteThread. Is there a way to get the address of sound.dll+1AE0 (or linkage) when the DLL is loaded without having to to do GetModuleHandleEx and calculate the address dynamically?

Maybe with some imports or some linkage artifact?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The GetModuleHandleEx approach will look like:

> DWORD mem1AE0=0;

Load mem1AE0 with sound.dll+1AE0 address

and then in my function:

```
_declspec(naked) void MyFunction() { 
    __asm { 
        mov edi,edi 
        push ebp 
        mov ebp,esp 
        mov eax, mem1AE0 
        mov eax, [eax] 
        push eax 
        mov ecx,[ebp+08] 
        mov eax,[ecx] 
        mov eax,[eax+0C] 
        push eax 
        call sound.dll+7C640 
        pop ebp 
        ret 0004 
    } 
}
```

The problem is when I have a call [sound.dll+XXXX] instruction

In that case I need to create a variable which will point to that memory

> DWORD memXXXX=0;

Load it with the correct address and also create a proxycall DWORD

> DWORD memXXXX_content=0;

and then do:

```
push eax 
mov eax, memXXXX 
mov eax, [eax] 
mov memXXXX_content, eax 
pop eax 
call memXXXX_content
```

which is totally inefficient unless I am doing somehting wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: I believe there is no way to get static links if you are dynamically loading your DLL.

Comment: what's the problem with calling GetModuleHandleEx or OpenProcess/ReadProcessMemory?

Comment: What is your end goal here? You are re-implementing the function exactly the same? If you have a specific change, it may be better to patch it in-place. Either that or place your hook at a more specific level.

Comment: Yes, I need to replace that function entirey. Exactly the same.

Comment: your second snippet should appear as "call [memXXXX_content]" because there is no form of absolute near call in x86, but that makes the whole thing equivalent to "call [memXXXX]".

Comment: peter, I tried it and it doesn't work. call [memXXXX] calls the mem itself and not its content

Comment: I believe there is no way to get static links if you are dynamically loading your DLL. Thanks to all who were interested.